# Async Functions are not invoked sequentially

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I have three async functions:

```
getAccounts = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await someAsyncJob();
        ...
    }
    catch(err) {
        ...
    }
}
getPages = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await someAsyncJob();
        ...
    }
    catch(err) {
        ...
    }
}
getDepositList = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await someAsyncJob();
        ...
    }
    catch(err) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here, I have functions named "getAccounts", "getPages", "getDepositList". I need to invoke these functions sequentially, so I wrote the code like this:

```
getData = async () => {
    try {
        await getAccounts();
        await getPages();
        await getDepositList();
    }
    catch(err) {
        ...
    }
}
```

As from this article(https://medium.com/@peterchang_82818/asycn-await-bible-sequential-parallel-and-nest-4d1db7b8b95c), it must be work sequentially but when I ran this, they are invoke together and all of my logic was messed up.

How do I run those functions sequencially?

Comment: An unrelated pointer: You don't *have to* wrap every `await` expression in a `try/catch` block. See this example: https://repl.it/M6Cn/3 - the error propagates throughout the function call chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the execution sees an await, it should only continue after the promise is resolved, or rejected, thus it should be sequentially. I hope you also do await getData()?

Comment: No, getData function is invoked from normal function.

Comment: Ah yeah, that shouldnt be a problem, sorry for confusion. What lets you assume that they are invoked "together"?

Comment: Oh well, I was pool. I invoked next each function inside of them after await, so that's why they invoked random. It's working, thanks.